# To call a function with arguments from external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

Here is a case:

I have a bunch of local HTML documents here and there on my laptop and some helper functions in `~/static/helper-funcs.js`.

A particular document may need to use one or more of these functions, but not all of them. And sometimes it may need to use one of these functions with arguments that are specific to this particular document but not other. Which means that I want something like this:

```
<script src="~/static/helper-funcs.js" funcs="foo('string1', 'string2'); bar()"></script>
<p>Here the document itself begins...</p>
```

This is just pseudo-code, of course. What will be the closest alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use two `<script>` tags. One to load the file, and a second one to call the functions.

```html
<script src="~/static/helper-funcs.js"></script>
<script>
foo('string1', 'string2');
bar();
</script>
```